# filling an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm just taking my OOP lessons and I've found on a practice that I did not understand the theory as I thought... basically for practicing I tried to create a class which contains all the scripts I need to use on a single page, and I went as follows:

```
 class pageScripts {
    protected $scripts = array(); //an array to storage the links to the scripts

    public function setScripts($link) {
        $this->scripts[] = $link; //filling the array with the links
    }

    public function __toString() {
       $output = '';
       foreach($this->scripts as $values) {
          $output .= "<script src=" . $values . "></script>";

       }
       return $output;
    }

} 

 $scripts = new pageScripts;
 $scripts->setScripts('link to the script');
 $scripts->setScripts('link to the script2');
 //var_dump ($scripts);
 print($scripts);
```

Now, in my dreams, it supposed to concatenate the links and make a cute script list, however it doesn't, also I made a `var_dump()` and the array is filled, I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: At first glance, it appears to me that what you have here should work (aside from the ugliness of not putting your script URLs in quotes when you output them).  What is it outputting?

Comment: it outputting nothing for me... I just put those ugly values to test...

Comment: Try view source, it should work fine. Does it work with real script names?

Comment: Yeah, I'm checking the output on the source code, but I see nothing =/

Comment: @andrewkthx: Is this literally what you have in the page?  There's no other code you're not showing us?

Comment: Well, [what's here works fine](http://ideone.com/BP5Sq2) (again, aside from the ugliness of the non-quoted URLs).  So i have to wonder what's different about your end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output & the code are fine (works for me), but by default PHP renders output with content type `text/html`, which "hides" the `<script>` tag.

To reveal the `<script>` tag, you can either set the content type to `text/plain` (which does not make sense), or review it in source code.

Comment: That's all the PHP codes you have in the page? Construct at least HTML structure.

Comment: thanks! I tried on a html sample I had, and worked fine, looks like i was waiting something different, meaning, I thought I was able to see it on the source code. thanks a ton again